# Object deconstruction assignment without variable declaration in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-next

Is it possible to have a deconstructing assignment expression in ES6 without the need of declaring variables?

In other words, why is the following code syntactically incorrect?

(I know there are a lot of ways this code could be rewritten.)

```js
'use strict';

let var1 = 'defaultVal1', var2 = 'defaultVal2';
const obj = { group: { var1: 'newVal1', var2: 'newVal2' } }
if (obj) {
  { group: { var1, var2 } } = obj; // No 'let'/'const' keyword, i.e. no redeclaration, but invalid expression
}
console.log(var1);
console.log(var2);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The brackets are interpreted as [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block), but you need an expression. This can be archived by wrapping it with parentheses as an [assignment without declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assignment_without_declaration).

```js
'use strict';

let var1 = 'defaultVal1', var2 = 'defaultVal2';
const obj = { group: { var1: 'newVal1', var2: 'newVal2' } }
if (obj) {
  ({ group: { var1, var2 } } = obj); // No 'let'/'const' keyword, i.e. no redeclaration, but invalid expression
}
console.log(var1);
console.log(var2);
```

Comment: @Rajesh `var1` is just the declared varibale from above.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring the variables, and the conditionally destructure, you can combine them, and use [short-circuit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation) evaluation to use a fallback (`|| {}`), and then use [defaults](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values_2) as the values:

```js
'use strict';

const obj = { group: { var1: 'newVal1', var2: 'newVal2' } };

const { group: { var1 = 'defaultVal1', var2 = 'defaultVal2' } = {}} = obj || {};

console.log(var1);
console.log(var2);
```

Comment: The accent was not on the `if` statement, this is just used an example for assigning variables from the parent scope.